# sql datediff problem

Tags: sql, datediff

I'm trying to calculate the difference between 2 dates, the current date and the date my members subscribed on the site. If the difference is more than 30 days, I turn off their subscription. I just can't get it to work.

```
$strFind="SELECT DATEDIFF(date, curdate()) AS total FROM `monthlydues` WHERE     `memid`=\"$curmemid\" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($strFind) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$gtime=$row['total'];

if($gtime>30){  
$strsql="UPDATE monthlydues SET `active`='N' WHERE `memid`=\"$curmemid\"";
mysql_query($strsql,$connect) or die(mysql_error());
$chkrow5=mysql_affected_rows($connect);
}
```

Comment: Which database system is that. Please specify because it matters, a lot.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What doesn't work?  What value of "total" is found?

Comment: It's a MYSQL Database, the value is wrong. $gtime is calculated as >30 and the database is updated setting table field active to 'N'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not one statement?

```
UPDATE monthlydues
SET `active`='N'
WHERE DATEDIFF(curdate(), date) > 30
```

So this?

```
$strsql="UPDATE monthlydues SET `active`='N' WHERE DATEDIFF(curdate(), `date`) > 30";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what kind of difference you want.

For SQL Server for example you specify a difference in days like this:

```
DATEDIFF(day, date, curdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

The following may help you, though it depends on exactly what you want to do; This query will operate on all members, not just the member identified by a specified id:

```
UPDATE monthlydues SET active = 'N' 
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), `date`) > 30;
```

If you wish to target a specific member, simply add a constraint:

```
UPDATE monthlydues SET active = 'N'
WHERE memid = :memberid 
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `date`) > 30;
```

**EDIT:** NOW() is a MySQL function. Is likely to be different on diff engines